# Would people be interested in having site organised photo meets?

Tags: site-promotion

The site works best with a strong sense of community, and I was thinking of things that we could do to help build this, and wondered if people would be interested in regional meet-ups/events? Even something simple like [this other photomeet](http://www.google.com/buzz/nickeblewis/5dGxapK3P5U/If-I-were-to-arrange-a-UK-Buzz-Photographers-Meet) where people agree on a date/time/location and go shooting, maybe swapping tips, lending gear, etc?

Comment: You mean like meetup.com?

Answer (score 3):

I might be interested, but I'm afraid I'm the only user in my country right now :-)

Comment: so we all just come to you, whats the issue? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think any online community is strengthened by offline social ties.

The key problem is (as @che notes), with only 1,500 registered users, critical mass might be achieved in only a few places around the world.

Answer (score 1):

I think, now that our site has grown a fair bit more, this might be more viable. It might be easier in large metropolitan areas, as the chances of knowing a PhotoSEer nearby is more likely. Long term, as we reach and surpass the 10k user mark, it might be possible to get some funding for an actual photography event. Reserve room and board somewhere for everyone who commits, have actual photography outings (i.e. street photography, landscape photography, etc.), and make it an actual event.

Answer (score 0):

So with some time having passed, and observing that there is someone pretty much next door to me in just the first reputation cohort, I think something like this would be really great.

Is there some way that people could propose a meetup and have the proposal sent to active people who have given a location that's nearby? If we have to rely on people seeing the notifications on meta IMO it's hopeless (because only the hardcore look here regularly), but if there was some way to be more pushy, it could work for the geographies who are fortunate enough to have a critical mass.

FWIW, I'm near Boston, MA, USA and would love to meet up with other photo-SE folks for beers (and perhaps some photography).

Comment: I know there are a couple PhotoSEers here in Denver. There has been some talk about meeting up, but it hasn't materialized yet. I would love to casually meet with some of my fellow PhotoSErs, but it doesn't seem as easy as it sounds. Long term, once we get bigger, I'd like to see more official, better organized events where people congregate within countries, or maybe even across countries. Probably need 10k or more users for that to work, though.

Comment: Oh hi, neighbor. :)